# Getting the result from API, http.post with Ionic2

Tags: angularjs, api, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have used this code to make a call on http.post

```
var creds = encodeURI("name="+name+"&email="+email);

var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

this.http.post('https://api.example.com/v1/auth/register', creds, {
    headers: headers
})
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(
  () => console.log('Registration Complete')
);
```

From the code above, the API may return an error message looks like below.

```
{ 
   "error": "Validation error.",
   "errors": [
      "The username has already been taken.",
      "The email must be a valid email address."
   ]
}
```

How I can get the error message from API request and display it?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in subscribe is the error, the third is 'finally'

```
this.http.post('https://api.example.com/v1/auth/register', creds, {
    headers: headers
})
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(
  () => console.log('Registration Complete')
), (err) => console.log(err);
```

Comment: No, I dont want the error. Actually I want that message return from API

Comment: Than its the first parameter, but you have it empty.. it should be
```this.http.post('https://api.example.com/v1/auth/register', creds, {
    headers: headers
})
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(
  (messageFromApi) => console.log(messageFromApi)
)```

Comment: Does the return message is still can be read with http.post even the API has header code 400?

Comment: if it returns code 400 that means an error code, and it will be caught in the second function like i showed in the answer. But sometimes people use OK CODE (200) and send an object that contains error property so you can just check if (response.error) throw error like in your case. That result that you receive may still be from code 200